# Why serialize time as timestamp instead of ISO-8601?

Tags: jackson, timestamp, iso8601

According to https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime Jackson will serialize times as the number of milliseconds since 1970 by default. If `SerializationFeature#WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` is set, it will serialize times using ISO-8601.

Obviously `2018-11-03T22:51:00.54-04:00` is a lot more readable than `1541299860.540000000`.

Why would anyone favor sending a timestamp over the wire instead of ISO-8601? Does it have any performance advantages perhaps?

Comment: It’s easier for *humans* to read, but a simple float is easier *machine readable* than a string that needs to be parsed…